# I tried to retrieving data from firebase database to tableview but I just got one element

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to retrieving data from Firebase database to tableview in `Xcode`
but I just got one element even if I have a lot of element in the database.

I followed a tutorial, I put return sonsList.count to `numberOfRowsInSection` as suppose but nothing happen.

**Here is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class sons  {
    let name : String!
    //let place : String!

init(title_String : String!){

    self.name = title_String
   // self.place = place_String
    }   
}

class sonsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var ref:DatabaseReference!

    //var  sons = [String]()
    var newSon: String = ""
    let cellId = "cellId"
    var refHandel : uint!
    var sonsList = [sons]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let name = value!["name"] as! String
            self.sonsList.append(sons(title_String : name))
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

        //fetchName()

    }

    func fetchName()  {

    }


    @IBAction func cancel(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {


    }

    @IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

        var sonDetailVC = segue.source as! addSonViewController
        newSon = sonDetailVC.name
        // sons.append(newSon)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sonsList.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        let label = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label.text = sonsList[indexPath.row].name

        return cell!
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You will get every time newly added record only

Comment: yes , first time I got the first element in the database then if I add one I just got it. how can I retrieve the all data??please

Comment: use valuechanged event `ref.child(" parrent of  name").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .valueChanged, with: { snapshot in

      

    })`

Comment: unfortunately the app crash after I adding this line  `ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in`

Comment: please share you firebase JSON structure, so I can explain more detail

Comment: `busy-parents
  name
  -L2tztP0FtzfUSJrwBfo
    Id: L2tztP0FtzfUSJrwBfo
    name: eren
 -L2u1F8xhgX17SQTtjTr
   Id: L32Li9f3P1vAjRtzwAL
   name: Jamey
 -L2u1HH8-gVncr_Pxahu
   Id: L2u1F8xhgX17SQTtjTr
   name: haru
 -L2u1KI-7Iz7CwkD9m-7
   Id: 
   name: 
 -L2y42zAgp43nOJlFzgn
 -L2y4Yq-82ShBJurcIAM
 -L2yIwC6jD44E00TNuoN
 -L2yJ92LdTUvHVMKBTSz
 -L2yJtamjy2HrQ7MqumI
 -L2yKFz_5Er-xEv3A2lS
 -L2yKMPw3Ia6g7LrvjQ-` and so on , sorry I exported Jason tree but when open give my authentication expired,so sorry  ,thank you

Comment: use valuechanged event ref.child("busy-parents").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .valueChanged, with: { snapshot in })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues in your Database query.

You append only one value in `sonsList`.

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        //Parse snapshot value correctly it is array or not.

      if let dicValue = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] { 
     for (key,value) in dicValue { 
             let name = value["name"] as? String
             self.sonsList.append(sons(title_String : name))
     }
             self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
})
```

Please refer this link for Get data in firebase Database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: `ref.child("name").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in` , I add this code and I observer got the data but the app crush

Comment: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and I just got 40 element of 50 and forget the first 4 elements

Comment: You have issues in **value!["name"] as! String**  . Could you print snapshot value. check whether it have value or not.

Comment: all the data has printed no nil data but when executing arrive `let name = value!["name"] as! String` break

Comment: okay great...do one thing check the value type it is a array or dictionary..else could you share value .. i will helpful to find exact issue

Comment: sorry , I am new to swift , how do I check the value type and I didn't get ".else could you share value" . thank you so much for your help

Comment: okay no worry .. Refer this link : [link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) in that  **// Example JSON with object root:** and **// Example JSON with array root:**

Comment: very sorry I tried but could not ,but when I print the data it's appear like this `["-L2z4zdrO-95Y4P-l78u": {
    Id = "-L2z4zdrO-95Y4P-l78u";
    name = Aloha;
}, "-L2yLuSZ5MPtA6_W2INg": {
    Id = "-L2yLuSZ5MPtA6_W2INg";
    name = "Taka ";
}, "-L2tztP0FtzfUSJrwBfo": {
    Id = "-L2tztP0FtzfUSJrwBfo";
    name = eren;
}, "-L2yLYtH4y47N57F6TaQ": {
    Id = "-L2yLYtH4y47N57F6TaQ";
    name = "Aramin ";
etc...`

Comment: this may help you try this :   `if let responseArray = snapshot.value as? [Any] {

for item in responseArray {
if let itemDic = item as? [String : Any] {

let key = dic.keys.first

if let data = itemDic[key] as? [String :Any] {

let name = data["name"] as? String
sonlist.append(name)
}
}
}`

Comment: unfortunately he doesn't enter the first loop

Comment: I am Sure , It will work .  for (key,value) in snapshot.value {
       print("key:\(key)")
       print("value:\(value)")
                    
if let data = value as? [String : Any] {
let name = data["name"] as? String 
sonlist.append(name)
}

}

Comment: sorry for taking a lot of your time, I have `Type 'Any?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'` error in `for (key,value) in snapshot.value` line . not that I removed all previous declarations

Comment: Hello Omar Diab , that is not a problem.. try this downcast your value if  let dicValue = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {  for (key,value) in dicValue {
       print("key:\(key)")
       print("value:\(value)")
                    
if let data = value as? [String : Any] {
let name = data["name"] as? String 
sonlist.append(name)
} 

}
} let me know it will work or not ?  this is my mail id : santhos3386@gmail.com you can text me further help. thank you.

Comment: thanks that work perfectly , I  really appreciate your help sir, have a nice day